# After migrating from a MySQL database to PostgreSQL, I get a query error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "after"

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql

I changed the database in the project from MySQL to PostgreSQL and made a query like this:

```
alter table book add image varchar(128) after currency;
```

I get this error: **Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "after"**

I suspect there's a syntax error somewhere, just not too sure where it might be.

Comment: In postgres, [there is no `after` (`postgres.org`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).

Comment: This is why there is documentation [Alter Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html).

Comment: In PostgreSQL, the column position is based on the order you add the columns. You can't specify the column position. See the PostgreSQL wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position Note the SQL standard does not obligate PostgreSQL to have this feature. It's a MySQL-ism.